# Cannot read from contract, even thought function is public

Tags: solidity, wallets, mist

I am trying to read a contract I just deployed, and it seems I am unable to do so, as indicated by the symbol next to "NO".

[image: Mist]

This makes no sense, however, because the function is totally public. Here is the implementation:

```
function doesRequestExist(address _institution, address _beneficiary, uint _achievementId) public view returns (bool exists) {
    return requestedPayouts[_institution][_beneficiary][_achievementId];
}
```

Why am I not allowed to call this function?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel dumb. I thought that symbol meant that I could not call the function because I was sure the value would be `YES` for the input parameters I was testing. As it turns out, other factors were causing it to return `NO`. Once I fixed those things, it started returning `YES` and the symbol changed to a checkmark.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your solution?

Comment: There is no difference in code for this particular example. All I had to do was provide the Mist wallet with values that return a `YES`, at which point, it did.